# How to add text at right to screen?

Tags: flutter

I want to add the report question text on the right side I tried the position widget but it doesn't work what I do?

I try to achieve-

[image]

code-

```
Positioned(
right: 0,
child: Row(
children: [
    Icon(Icons.report, color: Color(0xff0E5487),),
    TextButton(onPressed: () => {}, child: Text("Report Question",
        style: cstmTextStyle(fs: 18, fc:Color(0xff0E5487) ),)),
],
),),
```

Comment: could you add your full code?

Comment: did you tried mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, on the row widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to use a `Column` with `Spacer` widget instead of a `Stack`.
I made an example of you:

```
      Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  width: 160,
                  height: 160,
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  width: 160,
                  height: 160,
                )
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8,),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: const [
                Spacer(),
                Placeholder(fallbackWidth: 32, fallbackHeight: 32,),
                SizedBox(width: 8,),
                Text('Report Question')
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wrap Your Row With Alignment

```
Align(alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: const Row(
             
              ),
            ),
```